# getting undefined variable in sass

Tags: css, sass

I am new to sass and want to use a variable stored in a file named "_designs.scss". I want to use this variable in a file named "_component.scss". But I am getting *"Undefined variable: "$grey-light-2"* error. I have tried everything, but nothing is working, please help.

Below  is the "_component.scss" file.

```
@use "designs" as d;

.logo{
  height: 3.25rem;
}
.search{
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 40%;
  &__input{
    width: 90%;
    background-color: d.$grey-light-2;
    padding: .7rem .2rem;
    border-radius: 100px;
    border: none;
  }
  &__button{
    outline: none;
  }
  &__icon{
    height: 2.5rem;
    width: 2.5rem;
  }
}
```

This is "-designs.scss" file:

```
  $color--primary: #eb2f64;
  $color--grey-light-1: #faf9f9;
  $grey-light-2: #f4f2f2;
  $color--grey-light-3: #f0eeee;
  $color--grey-light-4: #ccc;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things I can think of:

1. Check the path (i.e., `@use "../../your/path/to/designs";`).
2. If you're using Visual Studio Code extension for compilation, use the one by [Glenn Marks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=glenn2223.live-sass).

---

**EDIT**

You should rename `_component.scss` to `component.scss`.

According to the [SASS official website](https://sass-lang.com/guide):

> A partial is a Sass file named with a leading underscore. You might name it something like _partial.scss. The underscore lets Sass know that the file is only a partial file and that it should not be generated into a CSS file.

Comment: The path is correct, all the files are under one folder(no sub-folder), and I am using parcel-bundler for compilation.

Comment: Thanks, it worked but I also have other files which are named the same way, and then all those files are imported in a "main.scss" file, those files run fine until I use a variable.

Comment: So, do you still have problems with other files?

Comment: Yes, the same problem occurred again with the current file only, now I have stopped using parcel-bundler and the files are working fine, I have no idea why. Even the file name doesn't matter, be it "_comp.." or "comp..".